# How to use QSizePolicy to fix height of QTextEdit in QVBoxLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextedit, qlayout, qsizepolicy

I am building an application in which I have implemented a feedback space for error and success messages in a scrollable QTextEdit widget. The QTextEdit widget creates a log-like similar output and I need to show only two-three lines instead of it taking almost half of the window.

The current output looks like this [Large QTextEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Fsy.png)

I have been researching a bit [QSizePolicy Doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtWidgets/QSizePolicy.html#qsizepolicy) but could not completely understand how to set the QSizePolicy to get the desired output.

Here is my current UI code for this window. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
def UI(self):
        #UI LAYOUT
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        self.console_out = QTextEdit(self)
        print(self.console_out.sizeHint())
        self.console_out.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, (QSizePolicy.ShrinkFlag | QSizePolicy.Fixed))
        # self.console_out.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.console_out.setReadOnly(True)
        self.console_out.setPlaceholderText('Plugin Ready!')

        self.scroll.setWidget(self.console_out)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)

        #NORTH STAR
        ico = QPixmap(cwd + "/ico/north.png")
        self.na = QGraphicsPixmapItem(ico)
        self.na.setTransform(QTransform.fromScale(0.1, 0.1), True)
        self.na.setTransformOriginPoint(self.na.boundingRect().center())
        self.canvas.scene().addItem(self.na)
        self.canvas.scene().update()
        #ROTATION
        self.rot = QSpinBox(self)
        self.rot.setRange(0.0, 360.0)
        self.rot.setSuffix(" °")
        self.rot.valueChanged.connect(self.rotateMapCanvas)

        self.bottom_split = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.bottom_split.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.bottom_split.addWidget(self.rot)
        self.bottom_split.setStretchFactor(0, 10)

        main_split = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        main_split.addWidget(self.canvas)
        main_split.addWidget(self.bottom_split)
        # main_split.setStretchFactor(100, 1)

        main_layout.addWidget(main_split)
```

Comment: I don't understand, you're asking about QLineEdit, but you're actually using a QTextEdit. What widget do you want to use? And, besides, why can't you just use [`setMaximumHeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#maximumHeight-prop)? If you want to know the exact size for 3 lines, get the [`fontMetrics()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#fontMetrics) of the widget, multiply it's `height()` by 3, and add the double of the frame width of the text edit.

Comment: @musicamante Sorry, I meant QTextEdit. I made the edits. Also, I tried setMaximumHeight() and It does not work.

Comment: It *does* work, if it didn't work for you then you probably used it wrongly or on the wrong widget. Please show us how you tried to do it.

Comment: Maybe because you should target the QScrollArea instead of the QTextEdit? Seems it would work, as the QTextEdit is inside the QScrollArea on your example. Btw, note that the QTextEdit already implements a QScrollArea inside it, so it shouldn't be needed to add another one.

Comment: @musicamante it did work. I had a brain fog moment when I tried setMinimumHeight instead of setMaximumHeight. Carl HR, I initially didn't have the scroll area, thanks I'll remove it. Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @nospec A small correction to what CarlHR pointed out: to be precise, QTextEdit does not "implement" a scroll area, it *is* a scroll area, since it inherits from QAbstractScrollArea; always remember to check the inheritance of the classes you're using: if you go to the [QTextEdit documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html), you'lll see QAbstractScrollArea listed in the section "Inherits" of its header. I also suggest you to take your time to study more about Qt size hints and policies; specifically, remember that the `Policy` enums are based on the widget's `sizeHint()`, but if does ->

Comment: @musicamante understood, I'm relatively new to this and still trying to figure how to completely understand documentation. As you can see I was on a slightly different path before you answered my question. Thank you I will.

Comment: @nospec -> implement `minimumSizeHint()` (which is the case of QAbstractScrollArea subclasses), that minimum size is always respected, except from the `Ignored` size policy or whenever the `sizeAdjustPolicy()` is *not* the default `AdjustIgnored`. The default "minimum" size hint of a Qt scroll area (such as QScrollArea, text viewers and item views) is always 256x192, it *can* become smaller if the user tries to resize the window, but when windows are first shown Qt will always try to get as much space as possible by respecting the `sizeHint()` of its widgets.